# Site is not indexed

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have submitted the sitemap to google webmaster tools however it is not getting indexed.

It has been almost a month since it has been submitted. The webmaster tools say "No data available." on almost every section.

As far as I can tell there is nothing blocking google from indexing, robots.txt as you can see is not blocking anything, no meta tags blocking crawling.

Here is a screen shot of the webmaster tools for the sitemap:
http://www.2shared.com/photo/4HLbsOte/webmaster.html
 I am not sure why it says Processed May 3 2012 when I submitted it earlier last month. But nothing has been indexed and looks like there are no issues with it either.

Any ideas?
Thanks for the help.

**SOLVED Edit:**

**looks like I had X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow in my http header.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow in my http header.

Answer (score 0):

In the sitemap section of webmaster tools, does it say that there are any errors with the sitemap you submitted?

Also, how many pages are in that sitemap? if there are very few pages, you are likely to see very low indexing because google usually doesn't index all of your pages

Comment: No there have been no errors. There are 666 pages on the sitemap. There are moderate amounts of traffic on this site every day (around 300 hits a day)

Answer (score 0):

There may be some issues when you submit sitemap of your website to google webmaster tool. You should try again to add sitemap. Just delete previous sitemap and add it again. I hope it will work now.